# Cython/python - List of cdef class

Tags: python, list, class, cython

I am trying to improve this code which uses list type :

```
# CLASS ORDERC #
################
cdef class OrderC:
    cdef int _side
    cdef float _px
    cdef int _vo

    def __cinit__(self, int side, float px, int vo):
        # ....

    cdef setData(self, double[:] dates):
        # ....

# CLASS LISTORDERC #
####################
cdef class ListOrderC:
    cdef int _B
    cdef list _LO_Bid

    cdef double[:] _dates

    def __init__(self, num.ndarray[num.double_t, ndim=1] dates):
        self._B = 0
        self._LO_Bid = []
        self._dates = dates

    cpdef addOrder(self, OrderC oo):
       self._B += 1
       self._LO_Bid.append(oo)
       self._LO_Bid[-1].setData(self._dates)
```

The problem arrives when i call addOrder from python :

```
 AttributeError: 'OrderC.OrderC' object has no attribute 'setData'
```

I guess it's because OrderC is recognized as python object, so I have to define setData with cpdef. But I want OrderC to be recognized as the cdef class to imporve the performance.

Could you please help me ?

Thanks

Comment: In the code you posted, the methods are not indented correctly. You just define a free function `setData()` independently from `OrderC`. You need to format the classes like you normal Python classes.

Comment: Yes, it is a mistake on the post only. In my code, the indentation is correct. I made corrections to this post.

Comment: Related 1) [arrays of cdef class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851333/cython-how-do-you-create-an-array-of-cdef-class) 2) About `AttributeErrors` when looking up classes in lists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067323/cant-use-attributes-of-a-class-from-a-list-of-that-classes-in-cython https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230665/cython-class-attributeerror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `list` only holds things of type `object`, so when you access you get back an `object`.

You probably want to use a C++ `vector` instead.

Comment: I was wondering whether `cdef OrderC orderc = self._LO_Bid[-1]` and `orderc.setData(...)` would work ?

Comment: Probably, but it's also likely to be slower because it has to check the types match and then unpack it. You can do unchecked casts, but even then a `vector` will be faster.

Comment: Sebdel's solution works but performs a bit slower than my current solution. Cython doesn't let me compile a vector of OrderC pointer cdef vector<OrderC*> but not cdef public vector<OrderC*>. So I think that it will slow down my code since I will have to cast it as python object every time I wnat to acces it from python.

Comment: If you want fast access from Python as well, you could make every `OrderC` store `object` pointers to itself and return those on access from Python. No guarantees it'll work, but I don't see why it wouldn't.