# A "C only" class in Cython

Tags: python, cython

Assume I define a class like:

```py
cdef class A:
    cdef int a
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.a = 0
```

Now I'd like to have an array of `A` in a different class:

```py
cdef class B:
    cdef A* b
    def __cinit__(self, SIZE_t n):
        self.b = <A*>realloc(self.p[0], sizeof(A)*n)
```

But I get the error:

`Pointer base type cannot be a Python object`

**EDIT:** I realized I didn't make it clear that I'm trying to have an array of dynamic length of `A` which I'm trying to `realloc` at some point, and that's why I have a pointer to that type.

**EDIT 2:** The basic requirements I have are:

- I have a self written class, of which I'm happy to have ONLY a C-interface.
- I need to have a dynamically allocated array, and a dynamically allocated array of arrays (or a pointer to pointers).

I understand the pointers are probably not the best way to go, and I'm happy if there's a better solution to it here. That's why I'd say it's not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851333/cython-how-do-you-create-an-array-of-cdef-class). I've read that one and it does not answer this question.

For more context, it's the `BitSet` I've introduce in this [scikit-learn/PR/commit](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/12866/commits/532061ff53db321cabcaa213e520a055ecec36df).

**EDIT 3:** For the one dimensional array, I may be able to use `memoryview`s like:

```py
    ...
    cdef A[:] b
    ...
    for i in range(n):
        b[i] = A()
```

But I'm not sure how to handle the two dimensional with variable lengths one. I just wish I could use something like the equivalent of `vector<vector<A>>`.

Comment: Doesn't the error explain that? The members of a C class (`class B`) can not be Python objects. This has nothing to do with `A` being defined with `cdef`, that's a misinterpretation.

Comment: > The members of a C class (class B) can not be Python objects
I know, that's why the title of the question is a "c only" class in cython. How can I make it not a python object @UlrichEckhardt?

Comment: You can have a single A object in B with `cdef A b` but not an array. You can define a C struct in Cython with `cdef struct A:` and access that through a pointer (but it can't have functions like `__cinit__` attached), or you can just create a Python list and fill it with `A`s

Comment: `Possible duplicate of cython: how do you create an array of cdef class`

could be, but that question also doesn't have an answer. Seems like we're getting an answer here though.

Comment: Sorry, I have overlooked the "array"-part. But basically you don't want to do that because of many reasons.

Comment: @ead maybe the second edit helps? I'm happy to use an alternative fast solution.

Comment: @adrin Since your `Bitset` class in the link only seems to store a 64-bit integer, I'd probably just use a (numpy) array of 64-bit integers instead of a class. Otherwise it'd be a case of using a `list` or an Numpy array of `object`, as I suggest in the linked question