# How do I define an array of objects of an extension type in Cython without using list?

Tags: python, cython

A `Bar` is associated with 0..6 `Foo`s. `Foo` is an extension type, like so

```
cdef class Foo:
    cdef double fooiness

    cdef void do_things(self):
        self.fooiness += 1
```

I make copies of `Bar`s very, very, very, very often. Ideally, I'd even like to be able to make copies of `Bar`s concurrently with threads, without the GIL. I can define `Bar` like this:

```
cdef class Bar:
    cdef list my_foos

    cdef Bar copy(self):
        cdef Bar the_copy = Bar.__new__(Bar)
        the_copy.my_foos[:] = self.my_foos[:]
        return the_copy
```

but as you can imagine, the `list[:] = list[:]` bit shows up bright yellow in the `-a` report.

I've tried `cdef Foo my_foos[6]`, but that gives me `Array element cannot be a Python object`

So I tried `cdef Foo * my_foos[6]`, but that gave me `Pointer base type cannot be a Python object`

I've considered abandoning the array entirely and going with `cdef Foo my_foo_1, my_foo_2...` but I'd like to iterate over my `Foo`s without having to hand-unroll the loop.

Searching variations on "how do I make an array of extension types in Cython" has turned up nothing relevant - which seems strange, since having arrays of things that aren't primitives is something you'd think a lot of people would want to do. I'm probably missing something obvious.

How do I make this work?

Comment: Duplicate of [cython: how do you create an array of cdef class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851333/cython-how-do-you-create-an-array-of-cdef-class)

Comment: Essentially the answer is "you can't really do this, and if you could then it would end up pretty close to a Python list, so just use a Python list". I'd probably change `the_copy.my_foos[:] = self.my_foos[:]` to `the_copy.my_foos = list(self.my_foos)` to make a copy but it'll be pretty similar performance-wise