# Cython: Can List Item Type be declared in Function Signature?

Tags: python, cython, type-declaration

I am using Cython and I want to declare a function whose argument is a list that contains instances of a cdef class. I have followed the [docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html) and I also found a workaround based on using a local variable to make it work. However, I would like to declare the type of the items in the list directly in the function signature. Is that at all possible?

As a simple example, consider the following extension type.

```
cdef class Shrubbery:
    cdef int width, height
    cdef float depth
```

Now assume, I like to define a function that uses an instance of that cdef class as an input. I can do this as follows:

```
cdef widen_shrubbery(Shrubbery sh, extra_width):
    sh.width = sh.width + extra_width
```

The type declaration `Shrubbery` in the function signature is required to access the attributes of the cdef class, because the Cython compiler must know that it is an instance of that type and not a generic Python object.

Now assume, I wand to define a function that uses a list of instances of that cdef class as inputs. My workaround is a solution that defines a local variable, inside the function, which is as follows:

```
cdef widen_shrubberies(list_of_sh, extra_width):
    cdef Shrubbery sh
    for i in len(list_of_sh):
        sh = list_of_sh[i]
        sh.width = sh.width + extra_width
```

But I wonder if it is possible to avoid using a local variable and instead declare the list containing instances `Shrubbery` directly in the signature of the function. Is it possible? How do I do this?

The code below does not cut it:

```
cdef widen_shrubberies(list Shrubbery list_of_sh, extra_width):
    for sh in list_of_sh:
        sh.width = sh.width + extra_width
```

Comment: It is not possible and there would be no performance benefit from it (Cython would have to generate a for loop checking that every element is of type `Shrubbery` - some thing it does on the fly when variable `sh` is typed anyway). You could write a cdef-class which would hold only elements of  `Shrubbery` thus eliminating the need for type-check.

Comment: This is relevant https://stackoverflow.com/q/33851333/4657412. Also, You can declare an plain list where you don't type the element (i.e. `list list_of_sh`) and that'll get you some benefit