# Cython class AttributeError

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I have started to experiment with Cython and ran into the following problem. Consider the following class representing a vertex in the 3D space:

```
#Vertex.pyx
cdef class Vertex(object):
    cdef double x, y, z
    def __init__(self, double x, double y, double z):        
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

Now I try to create an object from the Python console:

```
import Vertex as vt
v1 = vt.Vertex(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
```

which works fine. However, when I'm trying to access the class attributes, I'm getting an `AttributeError`:

```
print v1.x
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-83d928d774b7> in <module>()
----> 1 print v1.x

AttributeError: 'Vertex.Vertex' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Any ideas why this could happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `cdef` attributes are only accessible from within Cython. If [you make it a public attribute](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#static-attributes) with `cdef public` in front of the attribute name then Cython will generate suitable properties to be able to access it from Python.

---

*Some extra notes about related problems:*

If you're getting the same error from within Cython then you have probably forgotten to tell Cython the type of your instance variable (e.g. `v1`) - Cython itself can happily access `cdef` attributes but it only knows about them if it knows the type. If it's just a variable then `cdef` that variable. If you're trying to use the return value from a function, or index a list, or similar, then you can use a cast: `<Vectex>(func()).x`. *Only do this if you're certain of the type.*

You can get similar errors with `cdef` functions, which are again only visible within Cython. In this case `cpdef` makes the function visible from to both Cython and Python. However, `cpdef` functions are in some ways the worst of all worlds (they have all the limitations of `cdef` functions and all the limitations of `def` functions) - you're usually better choosing an Cython-only (`cdef`) or Python (`def`) interface.