# Why are some cdef's accessible and some aren't when accessing a Cython binary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

I have a class in a pyx file:

```
cdef class Qos:

    cdef object _policies

    def __cinit__(self, policies=[]):
        self._c_qos = dds.dds_qos_create()

    def set_policies(self, policies):
        self._policies[p.id] = p
```

When I am importing the compiled *.pyd file I can see the class `Qos`.

This works:

```
from dds import Qos
print(dir(Qos))
```

I read that `cdef`ed objects are not visible from Python, why can I see `Qos?

What I would really like to do is to access the also `cdef`ed attribute `Qos._c_qos` or `Qos._policies` from instances of `Qos`, but they are not available.

Is there a difference between these `cdef`s? Is there a setting on which
`cdef`s are exposed and which are not?

Comment: Part of your question is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230665/cython-class-attributeerror/55231514#55231514. The other part is just realising that a `cdef class` is different from `cdef typename variable_name`.

Comment: Do you mean that "cdef classes are extension types" as the doc mentions [here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html)?

Comment: Yes. `cdef class` defines an extension type which is visible from Python. It's a little inconsistent since most other uses for `cdef` make something not visible from Python. But it's more just realising that `cdef` means multiple (similar) things, and they are a bit inconsistent in places.