# Cythonizing numpy arrays within classes

Tags: python, numpy, cython, numpy-ndarray, cythonize

I want to change an attribute from a class within Cython, and I don't really understand why the following code gives rise to an error:

```
%%cython -a

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef class Prueba:

    def __init__(self, np.ndarray[np.float64_t] x, np.ndarray[np.float64_t] y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.x
    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.y
    cpdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t] change_x(self, np.ndarray[np.float64_t] new):
        self.x = new
        return self.x
```

>

```
A = Prueba(np.random.uniform(size=5),np.random.uniform(size=5))
```

>

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-2129c60d0253> in <module>
----> 1 A = Prueba(np.random.uniform(size=5),np.random.uniform(size=5))
      2 A

_cython_magic_2cd24205d75c05a3b692d063afd9549d.pyx in
_cython_magic_2cd24205d75c05a3b692d063afd9549d.Prueba.__init__()

AttributeError: attribute 'x' of '_cython_magic_2cd24205d75c05a3b692d063afd9549d.Prueba'
objects is not writable
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Not sure about CYthon, but this you would expect in plain python. Why are you using `property`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Because I want  access to this attribute later on python workspace

Comment: So? You don't need `property` for that. In any case, the problem is you haven't defined a setter, but if all that is going to do is set the attribute, just remove the `property` altogether.

Comment: That doesn't work for me, when I try to implement an __setattr__ method to the class, I get the following error:

can't apply this __setattr__ to _cython_magic_6dd954b7802b61c2cab9708c7edb58df.Prueba object

Comment: I **never mentioned `__setattr__`**. Why would you implement that? Again, **just remove** `@property def x(self) ... ` and `@property def y(self) ...` they **serve no purpose** and it doesn't seem like you understand what they are for, but you don't need them, so just leave them out.

Comment: This will be a duplicate of either https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632297/mixing-cdef-and-regular-python-attributes-in-cdef-class or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230665/cython-class-attributeerror. For a `cdef class` you __must__ declare the attributes and to access them from Python you __must__ make them public. And if you want to use `property` make sure you understand what it does in Python

Comment: Ok, I've remove @property methods, but when I try to declare "cdef public np.ndarray[np.float64_t] x,y" within __init__ it throws me an error, which states "Local variable cannot be declared public"

But, if I put the "cdef public np.ndarray[np.float64_t] x,y" outside __init__, at class level, then I get "Buffer types only allowed as function local variables".

So, what is it?? It returns and error regardless of where I place the cdef code

Comment: The declaration needs to be outside `__init__` at the class level. However it cannot be for type `np.ndarray[np.float64_t]` (a buffer type). jttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808216/cython-buffer-declarations-for-object-members. Instead either don't type it (`cdef public x,y`) or use the newer memoryview types.